# Bounding $\int_0^T\|u\|_{L^2}^{(6-s)r/2s}\|u\|_{L^6}^{(3s-6)r/2s}$ when $u\in L^\infty(0,T; L^2) \cap L^2(0,T;L^6)$ and $\frac2r +\frac3s\geq\frac32$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, bochner-spaces

Suppose $u \in L^\infty(0, T; L^2) \cap L^2(0,T; L^6)$  and
$$\frac2r + \frac3s = \frac32, \quad 2 \leq s \leq 6.$$
I am following a proof that states that
$$\int_0^T \|u\|_{L^2}^{(6-s)r/2s} \|u\|_{L^6}^{(3s-6)r/2s}$$
is bounded when $(3s-6)r/2s \leq 2$, or equivalently, when
$$\frac2r + \frac3s \geq \frac32.$$
I am having some trouble seeing why this is, I am guessing part of it has to due with working in Bochner spaces which I am very new to. How does this bound imply that the integral is finite?

Comment: This condition makes the exponent on the $L^6$ norm at most $2$ and hence the time integral of it is finite given the Bochner space $u$ lives in. The other factor, the one involving the $L^2$, is not a matter of worry since it is bounded in time on a finite time interval and hence in $L^p$ in time for any $p\in[1,\infty]$.

Comment: @Nick Thank you, so $\|u\|_{L^6}^{(3s-6)r/2s}$ is finite whenever the exponent is $\leq 2$ because it is assumed $u \in  L^2(0,T; L^6)$? More generally, is this a property of Bochner spaces that if $u \in L^q(0,T; L^p)$, then $\|u\|_{L^p}^n$ is finite whenever $n \leq q$? I assume this is the same reasoning you used for the $\|u\|_{L^2}^{(6-s)r/2s}$ term since it is assumed to be in $L^\infty$ (hence bounded)?

Comment: This is not a property of Bochner spaces but rather Lebesgue spaces. You have $\int_0^T \|u(t)\|_6^{2}dt<\infty$ by hypothesis so by the embedding $L^2\hookrightarrow L^p$ for all $p\in [1,2]$ you get $\int_0^T \|u(t)\|_6^{p}dt<\infty$ for free.

Comment: @Nick Thank you very much, I understand now.

Comment: @Nick If I may ask one more question, the embedding $L^2\hookrightarrow L^p$ assumes that our measure space has finite measure, how do we justify this? In the Bochner case, what is considered as the underlying measure space, the interval $[0,T]$?

Comment: Yes, you are viewing the outer Levesgue norm as measuring the function $t\mapsto\|f(t)\|_6$. So the underlying measure space is indeed $[0,T]$ and you are looking at the $L^p$ norm over this set of the function described above.

Comment: Thank you for all your help and patience!